# Wordpress Ajax custom taxonomy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i currently have a wordpress with a custom post type and a custom taxonomy attached to this. ( jobs_category ).

I have the build listing out the categories from this taxonomy like so:

```
<?php
  $taxonomy = 'jobs_category';
  $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
  <?php
  foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {?>
    <li id="cat-<?php echo $tax_term->term_id; ?>">
     <a href="#<?php //echo esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)); ?>" class="<?php echo $tax_term->slug; ?> ajax" onclick="cat_ajax_get('<?php echo $tax_term->term_id; ?>');" title="<?php echo $tax_term->name;?>"><?php echo $tax_term->name; ?></a>
    </li>
  <? } ?>
</ul>
```

I have then used the following in my functions file:

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
function prefix_load_cat_posts () {
    $cat_id = $_POST[ 'cat' ];
         $args = array (
        'cat' => $cat_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'order' => 'DESC'

    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    ob_start ();

    foreach ( $posts as $p ) { ?>

    <div id="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
        <h1 class="posttitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

        <div id="post-content">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

        </div>
   </div> 


   <?php } wp_reset_postdata();

   $response = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();

   echo $response;
   die(1);
}
```

To do the AJAX with the following JS:

```
    <script>
function cat_ajax_get(catID) {
    jQuery("a.ajax").removeClass("current");
    jQuery("a.ajax").addClass("current"); //adds class current to the category menu item being displayed so you can style it with css
    jQuery("#loading-animation-2").show();
    var ajaxurl = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {"action": "load-filter", cat: catID },
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery("#category-post-content").html(response);
            jQuery("#loading-animation").hide();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

My question is how do i get it to use the custom taxonomy categories? Im not 100% sure because i've never done it before.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use [**`tax_query`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) instead of `cat`. While [**`category`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) is used for native Wordpress taxonomy, so it won't work for custom taxonomies.

Replace your array `$args` to this:

```
$args = array (
    'tax_query' => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'jobs_category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array( $cat_id )
         )
    ),
    'post_type' => 'jobs', // <== this was missing
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I think I understand what you are saying, basically instead of looking for cat i need to look for tax_query.

My current code now looks like this : http://pastebin.com/jAquKr73  however it doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: @andyjones Can you explain not working? What else its outputting?

Comment: Sorry should have explained, it loads nothing. Nothing loads into:
<div id="category-post-content"></div> I did console.log(data); to check what might be loading, there is nothing :/

Comment: @andyjones Ah i got it. You said you have custom post type but you haven't defined any `post_type` to your `$args` array. As i said Wordpress think you mean `post_type => post` which is native and this not in your case. Whats your `post_type` by the way? Then i will edit my answer.

Comment: ahh right, i have put all my custom post type in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/L9KHfqvA  register_post_type( 'jobs', $args ); thanks very much :)

Comment: Something seems to be working from that :) i just need to figure how to pull in the custom fields now. Thanks for all the help.